# Having Trouble Rendering an Object Passed Down in Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

**Hey Guys**,
this is my first post on Stack Overflow, but I will do my best to adhere to the proper formats! To sum it up, I have spent the last five hours on this react component, trying to render a list of objects being passed down from the state of my parent component, through the child's props. I have tried every which way, researched multiple solutions, but nothing is seeming to work. This is my first time using webpack, maybe there is some plugin I have to download for using React state and props? I dunno. Anyways, I will post snippets below and describe each step to the best of my ability.

### My Parent App

I have had no trouble on this end, I have logged my results every step of the way so I know for a **fact** that the *getWeather* function is properly fetching data from the Weatherbit API and setting the state, which in turn as you will see, passes the array to the child via it's props.

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {weatherArray: []}
    this.getWeather = this.getWeather.bind(this);
}


getWeather() {
    const newWeather = WeatherHelper.inputPrompt();
    console.log(newWeather)
    this.setState({weatherArray: newWeather})
    WeatherHelper.showData()

}
```

### Still on My Parent App

As you can see, I pass the state as a prop to the child, which would update soon as *setState* runs

```
<div id='side-apps'>
    <div id='weather-side-app'>
        <WeatherApp weatherArray={this.state.weatherArray} />
    </div>
</div>
```

### My Child App

**So this is where it gets weird...**
This is my child component, and as you can see when the component receives new props, it first checks whether or not those props are updated. Then, assuming those props are new, the *componentWillReceiveProps* method will set the state and re-render accordingly (or so you would think). You can also see that I have extensively used logging to try to document my problem, which I will provide a screen shot of next. Notice that in the *componentWillReceiveProps* method, if the props are different than the originals (i.e. updated) the method will log multiple dashes around the updated props so you can point them out (you'll see). By the way, I understand that I shouldn't even have to use the *componentWillReceiveProps* method, the parents *setState* function alone should have been enough to update my component, but alas it did not (and neither did the other 10 different ways I tried).

```
class WeatherApp extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {currentWeather: []}
}

handleCloseClick() {
    WeatherHelper.hideData();
}


componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.weatherArray !== this.state.currentWeather) {
        console.log('---')
        console.log(nextProps.weatherArray)
        console.log('---')
        this.setState({currentWeather: nextProps.weatherArray})
    } else {
        {console.log("if you see an array under this comment," +
            "that means the above if statement read the state's 
             currentWeather array's length" +
            " as zero. EVEN THOUGH the componentWillReceiveProps method" +
            " updated and set the state accordingly...")}
        console.log(nextProps.weatherArray)
        console.log(this.state.currentWeather)
    }
}



render() {

    if (this.state.currentWeather.length > 0) {
        return (
        <div class='weatherApp-main'>
            <div className='close-sidebar-button'>
                <img src='https://i.postimg.cc/hj0rYKxc/close-button.png' onClick={this.handleCloseClick}/>
            </div>
            <div id='weather-app-header'>
            <h2>{this.state.currentWeather}</h2>
                <h3></h3>
                <h4></h4>
            </div>
            <div id='weather-app-table'>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    } else {
        {console.log(this.state.currentWeather)}
        return <p></p>
        }
    }


}
```

### Child Component Logging Details

if you look the the screen shot, you can see that my logging from my child's *componentWillReceiveProps* method proves that the setState function **must** have been called, but for some reason it does not update the child's html and display data.

[child component logging details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i78n.png)

### Child Component React Details

Okay last thing... I also am posting the react chrome dev tool that shows you what components have props and states. You can see in this image, that the child component **did** receive the intended props and updated it's state accordingly. **But again, for some reason it will not allow me to access them and display results**

[child component react details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgXEl.png)

I really apologize if this question is too lengthy... And yes, I understand that there are multiple similar posts already solved, but I have looked at most of them, and my situation just does not apply from what I can tell... I am not an expert, but I am no newbie to react. This has really stumped me. **Thank you so much in advance for your help**. I can provide additional screenshots, code snippets, or even videos if that helps!!!

makezi

## EDIT

I added replace the block of code with a map function, and as you can see, the problem is not how I am delivering the data to the DOM. The problem is for some reason, my component is not reading the data in it's state (I will post a more detailed screenshot to better document the problem)

```
render() {
    console.log('++++')
    console.log(this.state.currentWeather.length);

    if (this.state.currentWeather.length > 0) {
        return (
        <div class='weatherApp-main'>
            <div className='close-sidebar-button'>
                <img src='https://i.postimg.cc/hj0rYKxc/close-button.png' onClick={this.handleCloseClick}/>
            </div>
            <div id='weather-app-header'>
            {this.state.currentWeather.map(item => <div><span>{item.city}</span></div>)}
                <h3></h3>
                <h4></h4>
            </div>
            <div id='weather-app-table'>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    } else {
        {console.log("if you see an array under this comment," +
            "that means the above if statement read the state's currentWeather array's length" +
            " as zero. EVEN THOUGH the componentWillReceiveProps method" +
            " updated and set the state accordingly...")}
        {console.log(this.state.currentWeather)}
        return <p></p>
        }
    }
```

[better logging details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF9Rj.png)

### Second Edit for Minh Hưng Trần's Comment

I updated my parent's getWeather function to be asynchronous, also edited logging to be more descriptive. You can see **even though the currentWeather array in state has 8 objects, the length is still being read as zero!** I don't think the problem is comparing the arrays. For some reason, my render function cannot read the data in my state... or it is not being updated when setState is ran. **you cannot tell from the screenshot, but the nextProps array is read and fully logged to console. although after running setState, the ''console.log(this.state.currentWeather)'' logged an empty array, weird right? **

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.weatherArray !== this.state.currentWeather) {
        console.log("--nextProps weatherArray--")
        console.log(nextProps.weatherArray)
        console.log('--------------------------')
        this.setState({currentWeather: nextProps.weatherArray})
        console.log("==child's state==")
        console.log(this.state.currentWeather)
        console.log("=================")
    } else {
        console.log(nextProps.weatherArray)
        console.log(this.state.currentWeather)
    }
}



render() {
    console.log("++child's state's length in render method++")
    console.log(this.state.currentWeather.length);
    console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")

    if (this.state.currentWeather.length > 0) {
        return (
        <div class='weatherApp-main'>
            <div className='close-sidebar-button'>
                <img src='https://i.postimg.cc/hj0rYKxc/close-button.png' onClick={this.handleCloseClick}/>
            </div>
            <div id='weather-app-header'>
            {this.state.currentWeather.map(item => <div><span>{item.city}</span></div>)}
                <h3></h3>
                <h4></h4>
            </div>
            <div id='weather-app-table'>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    } else {
        {console.log("if you see an array under this comment," +
            "that means the above if statement read the state's currentWeather array's length" +
            " as zero. EVEN THOUGH the componentWillReceiveProps method" +
            " updated and set the state accordingly...")}
        {console.log(this.state.currentWeather)}
        return <p></p>
        }
    }
```

[better logging details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q87Id.png)

**To reiterate, in my componentwillreceiveprops function: the "console.log('nextProps.weatherArray)" DOES emit the full array of data... HOWEVER, the "console.log('this.state.currentWeather)" does NOT. Even after setState is run. But then when I use the React Chrome Dev Tools, you can see that the state DID in face get passed to the child component. My render method just cannot read the data for some reason..**

---

## THIRD EDIT

This first snippet is my parent component. You can see that it is passing the weatherArray to the child's props. This getWeather function DOES work by the way, I have been validating it through logging. The problem is on my child's end,I am sure of it.

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {weatherArray: []}
    this.getWeather = this.getWeather.bind(this);
}


async getWeather() {
    const newWeather = await WeatherHelper.inputPrompt();
    console.log(newWeather)
    this.setState({weatherArray: newWeather})
    WeatherHelper.showData()

}

render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <div id='main'>
                <div id='introduction'>
                    <Intro />
                </div>
                <div id='attachment'>
                    <Attachment getWeather={this.getWeather} />
                </div>
                <div id='body'>
                    <div id='about'>
                        <About />
                    </div>
                <div id='personal-info-skills'>
                    <div id='info'>
                        <p id='info-header'>personal information</p>
                        <Info />
                    </div>
                    <div id='pskills'>
                        <p id='pskills-header'>personal skills</p>
                        <PSkills />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='divider'>
                <p></p>
                </div>
                <div id='professions-languages'>
                    <div id='professions'>
                        <p id='professions-header'>professions</p>
                        <Professions />
                    </div>
                    <div id='languages'>
                        <p id='languages-header'>languages</p>
                        <Languages />
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id='side-apps'>
                <div id='weather-side-app'>
                    <WeatherApp weatherArray={this.state.weatherArray} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
}
```

}

Now I will post my child's code snippet after commenting out componentWillReceiveProps. Instead of trying to display data in my child's state, now I am simply trying to use props data that was passed from the child's parent component. Unfortunately, I am still running into the same problem. My child's render function is reading the props array as empty, and therefore cannot display data. I can't take away that if statement at the beginning of the render method because then my code throws errors when it tries to read attributes of an empty array

```
render() {

    if (this.props.weatherArray.length > 0) {
        return (
        <div class='weatherApp-main'>
            <div className='close-sidebar-button'>
                <img src='https://i.postimg.cc/hj0rYKxc/close-button.png' onClick={this.handleCloseClick}/>
            </div>
            <div id='weather-app-header'>
            {this.props.weatherArray.map(item => <div><span>{item.city}</span></div>)}
                <h3></h3>
                <h4></h4>
            </div>
            <div id='weather-app-table'>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    } else {
        {console.log("if you see an array under this comment," +
            "that means the above if statement read the state's currentWeather array's length" +
            " as zero. EVEN THOUGH the React Chrome Dev Tools shows that" +
            " the child has a full currentWeather array in props...")}
        {console.log(this.state.currentWeather)}
        return <p></p>
        }
    }


}
```

[before running getWeather function screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL67f.png)

[after running getWeather function screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQcsx.png)

**Look at the two above screenshots. The first one is before I run my fetch function, so the React Chrome Dev Tools show my child's props array is empty (of course). BUT the after screen shot shows that even though the React Dev Tools show my child component's props has a full array, my render method still reads that prop array's length as 0....**

Comment: I'm unsure why you're attempting to display currentWeather in a h2 tag since currentWeather is an array with objects - this should throw an error. I suggest looping it with .map, i.e. this.state.currentWeather.map(item => <div><span>{item.city}</span><span>...</span></div>)

Comment: I have tried that, here I will do it right now and show you. Sorry I should have reverted that back to normal. Thanks for your response!

Comment: if you look at the screenshot after the edited piece of code, I changed it so it also shows the react component's props & state. It clearly shows that the currentWeather array is full of data... I can't figure out why my render method is not picking up that data. **I can add a link to a git-hub repository if anyone would like to see the full code, just ask!**

Comment: Please show us where you are calling getWeather.

Comment: `setState` is an async method so your console.log would possible still print the empty array. You can test this by doing `setState({currentWeather: nextProps.weatherArray}, () => console.log(this.state))` which will run the console.log function as a callback after completion of `setState`. Also, is there any specific case why your child component has to maintain state of the same array as the parent? My bet is `componentWillReceiveProps` is the issue here as it's a synchronous function (will receive mismatched renders when dealing with async fetches, hence why it's deprecated since React 16.3)

Comment: hey guys thanks for the help! I just updated and remove componentWillReceiveProps, I will post an edit to main post now and show you.

Comment: Hey guys look at my third edit. It will clarify what I have been trying to convey. My render method is not able to read and retrieve my child component's props. Look at the code snippets and screen shots you will see what I mean. Thank you so much for your help...!!!

Comment: Hey guys and gals, does anyone else have any ideas? I still have not been able to figure this out.. I can post the full code on github if that would help. Thanks!

Comment: Why does the console.log in your getWeather function give an empty array after the fetch call?

Comment: Hey Craig, it doesn't. It logs a full array, maybe it just looks empty in the picture because of how it is displayed to log? When you click on it, it's full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React documentation suggests avoiding legacy lifecycles such as componentWillReceiveProps.

> A common misconception is that getDerivedStateFromProps and componentWillReceiveProps are only called when props “change”. These lifecycles are called any time a parent component rerenders, regardless of whether the props are “different” from before. Because of this, it has always been unsafe to unconditionally override state using either of these lifecycles. Doing so will cause state updates to be lost.

Documentation says:

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted... If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

**EDIT:**
Looking at the third edit, I've been assuming that you were fetching calls through the `componentDidMount` lifecycle, since you kept iterating that the fetching 'works'.

Since the snippets above do not actually show a `componentDidMount` method, I suggest trying to move all fetching logic to the appropriate `componentDidMount` method then setting state from there.

Comment: Hey Abe thanks for your input. I will give that a shot. Unfortunately, the problem is no longer passing down the correct props and updated the state accordingly. If you look at my post's third edit, you will see that I removed the componentWillReceiveProps method and the child component's state, and kept it simple, where my parent component passed down a prop to the child, and the child accessed it as a prop. That still didn't work though, if you look at the screen shot in my third edit, the React Chrome Dev Tools show that the props were properly passed down to the child..(cont...)

Comment: ..... but for some reason, my child was not able to access or read them in the render statement. Maybe because the props were being updated after my child component was rendered? It is blowing my mind, I cannot for the life of me figure out why my child component cannot read it's props.

Comment: Hey Abe, so `componentWillMount` is only called on the first time the component is rendered, correct? So in my case, I only need the data after the component is updated. I tried using the neccesary react lifecycle methods, but nothing has worked. My child component's render method can not read it's props. I am going nuts

Comment: Hey guys and gals, does anyone else have any ideas? I still have not been able to figure this out.. I can post the full code on github if that would help. Thanks!

Comment: yea that could be helpful, i'll try to reproduce it in my machine

Comment: Hey Abe, pasting link below. I will be making the repository private again in a day or two, please let me know when you get a chance to fork it or look at it. Thanks! https://github.com/rusty1996/resume-app

Comment: P.S. -- I have split each react component into it's own directory, hope it is not too confusing.. The ones you will be interested in are "App/" (the parent component), "SideApps/" (the child component), "helpers/" (the fetch function, which I really do not think is the problem by the way), and maybe "Attachment/" (where the whole process is started with the click of an icon).

Comment: hey man, i created a fork, got it working, you can check it if you want. i could do a pull request. your app looks great 
https://github.com/abetoots/resume-app

Comment: Abe, I just looked it over,  you are the best. I will try it out soon as I get home today around 6pm Eastern Time. I appreciate you cleaning and touching a few things up too.. Any idea what made the difference? Was it the App component? Thank you so much. P.S. I will set to answered soon as I test it out tonight!

Comment: ***IT WORKS*** Thanks my man. Much appreciated.... I learned from your style too, thanks alot.

Comment: awesome! was worried that refactoring your code would be too intrusive of me. glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

First, the `getWeather` function is fetching Weatherbit API, so you must use await
on fetch function. In your code above, I think you use function `WeatherHelper.inputPrompt()` to fetch data, so the function will be:

```
async getWeather() {
    const newWeather = await WeatherHelper.inputPrompt();
    console.log(newWeather)
    this.setState({weatherArray: newWeather})
    WeatherHelper.showData()
}
```

In your code above, `console.log` was print data because it can print data asynchronous (according to my experience).

Second, you shouldn't compare array with array by !==, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript).

Please change your code, if not working, please log data of nextProps and state of Child component in componentWillReceiveProps and show me the screenshot of it.

Sorry my english very bad.

Comment: Just updated the logging. To reiterate, in my componentwillreceiveprops function: the "console.log('nextProps.weatherArray)" DOES emit the full array of data... HOWEVER, the "console.log('this.state.currentWeather)" does NOT. Even after setState is run. But then when I use the React Chrome Dev Tools, you can see that the state DID in face get passed to the child component. My render method just cannot read the data for some reason..

Comment: I want to see the log of nextProps (not nextProps.weatherArray)

Comment: Hey Minh, sorry I ended up getting ridve the componentWillReceiveProps. Instead of trying to display data from my child component's state, I am now simply trying to display data in the child's props, passed down from it's parent component. If you look at my third edit, you will see that even though React Chrome Dev Tools shows that my child component's props is full of data, my child component's render method cannot read it...

Comment: You can try `this.forceUpdate()` in parent after setState: `this.setState({ weatherArray: newWeather }, () => this.forceUpdate());`

Comment: And what happen when WeatherHelper.showData() was called ?

Comment: WeatherHelper.showData just accessed the DOM and changes my div's width by using ""document.getElementById('exampleId').style.width = 'some width' ""

Comment: I am assuming forceUpdate rerenders the whole component? It doesn't reset the props or state does it? Thanks so much for your help, I will be home later today in 7 hours, and will try it then.

Comment: Hey guys and gals, does anyone else have any ideas? I still have not been able to figure this out.. I can post the full code on github if that would help. Thanks!

Comment: Post full code on github and give me the link, i'll find the solution for you

Comment: Hey Minh, I am pasting link below. Thanks! I will be making the repository private again in a day or two, please let me know when you get a chance to check it out. Thank you so much. https://github.com/rusty1996/resume-app

Comment: P.S. -- I have split each react component into it's own directory, hope it is not too confusing.. The ones you will be interested in are "App/" (the parent component), "SideApps/" (the child component), "helpers/" (the fetch function, which I really do not think is the problem by the way), and maybe "Attachment/" (where the whole process is started with the click of an icon).

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to use componentWillReceiveProps. This is adding a lot of unnecessary complexity for you. When the state changes in the parent component, it automatically re-renders its children. Omit the componentWillReceiveProps and render in the child component using this.props.weatherArray.

Comment: Hi Craig thank you for your response. I understand that, I mentioned the same thing earlier. I just reverted back to how I had it, like you said. I had my parent component pass down the weatherArray as a prop to the child, and commented out the componentWillReceiveProps. BUT STILL, in my render method, the if statement checking if the props weatherArray is empty still came up with empty...

Comment: And again, when I use the React Chrome Dev Tools, it shows that my child's props is full with the data array. Just for some reason, my render method cannot read the props or state...

Comment: Hey Craig look at my third edit and you will see what I am trying to convey. My child component's render method is not able to read my child's props for some reason. The two screen shot's and code snippets should do a good job describing what I mean. Hope that clarifies my problem... Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey guys and gals, does anyone else have any ideas? I still have not been able to figure this out.. I can post the full code on github if that would help. Thanks!